# Symfony multicompany application

Tags: symfony

I need to set up several parameters after user authentication.

We have a db with with oauth2 clients.
When one of them got access token and is trying to get access to protected API I need to identify the client (which is easy since access_token is bound to particular client) and define several application parameters (actually I need to load a specific file parameters.yml depends on the client).

My questions is:

1. How can I hook to event when user is authenticated?
2. How can I load a particular parameters.yml and make it relevant after user authenticate ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

1. When user is successfully authenticated, you can write a listener which listens to SecurityAuthenticationEvents::AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS.

The public method of the listener should look like this:

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(AuthenticationEvent $event)
{
    /**
     * @var User $user
     */
    $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();

    // ...

    return;
}
```

2. I believe you can use YamlFileLoader for that. Of course you can create a service class to read the contents from yaml files and provide them to different services in your app. I would not try to mix them with regular parameter / config files.

Comment: Thank you. "I would not try to mix them with regular parameter / config files." - why ? What is the possible alternative?

Comment: Well, the thing is the configuration is loaded before authentication. I had to do something similar in the past and ended up writing a solution without modifying the existing configuration. But if you can achieve that and works for you, you can of course do it. I am not sure, but you can maybe run into problems with dependency injection container.

Comment: The container parameters rule is that: You can only set a parameter before the container is compiled

Comment: Exactly. Also keep in mind that configuration is based on app environment, making it dependant on authenticated user sounds wrong.